# How to check full string for consonant-vowel pattern and return boolean value?

Tags: python, string

I have a project that requires me to check a encoded PIN which must have this pattern: consonant, vowel. For example, 3464140 is bomelela.

I previously tried this:

```
def checkString(st):
    if st == '':
        return False
    elif st[0] in consonants and st[1] in vowels:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

However string length can vary so I'm not so sure how to check the entire string.

This function should return a boolean value. I think I'm close, but I'm not sure how to return true or false given that my if statements end with i + 1.

So far I have this:

```
consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwyz"
vowels = "aeiou"

def checkString(st):
  for i in range(len(st)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
      if st[i] in consonants:
         i + 1
    elif i % 2 != 0:
      if st[1] in vowels:
         i + 1
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for any formatting issues, this is my first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple changes can do the trick for you :

```
consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwyz"
vowels = "aeiou"


def checkString(st):
    for i in range(len(st)):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            if st[i] not in consonants:
                return False
        else:
            if st[i] not in vowels:
                return False
    return True
```

Comment: *"This* **simple** *changes can to the* **trick** *for you"* - lol

Answer (score 0):

We can check the particular string in consonants or vowels at particular position and continue to next iteration as soon as the condition evaluates to true in the current iteration.

If any of the condition fails in any iteration, it will return to false. If the condition evaluates to True for all iterations, finally the function will return True.

```
consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwyz"
vowels = "aeiou"

def checkString(st):
    for i in range(len(st)):
        if i % 2 == 0 and st[i] in consonants:
            continue
        elif i % 2 != 0 and st[i] in vowels:
            continue
        else: 
            return False 

    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def checkString(teststring):
    '''To check for pattern: Consonant:Vowel and return true if pattern exists'''
    const = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwyz"
    vowels = "aeiou"
    t_odd = teststring[::2].lower()
    t_even = teststring[1::2].lower()
    outcome = ["True" if x in const else "False" for x in t_odd ] + ["True" if y in vowels else "False" for y in t_even]
    return all(item == "True" for item in outcome)

#Test
checkString("Bolelaaa")
checkString("bomelela")
```

In this function I'm using list comprehension to test odd & even letters against the list of consonants and vowels respectively. If all the comparisons hold true, the function returns true.